# Inferring types in Typescript - : vs =

Tags: javascript, typescript

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#inferring-the-types

> Inferring the types In playing with the example, you may notice that
> the TypeScript compiler can figure out the type even if you only have
> types on one side of the equation:

```
// The parameters 'x' and 'y' have the type number
let myAdd = function (x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
};

// myAdd has the full function type
let myAdd2 : (baseValue: number, increment: number) => number = function (x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

What does it mean when `:` is written instead of `=` here:

`let myAdd =`
`let myAdd2 :`

Comment: it's the typescript syntax, after adding ":" you mention the function definition or the type of variable which it is.

Comment: It's not a "vs", there's an `=` in both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, `:` is used to explicitly indicate the type of a variable or parameter.

So we have:

```
let myAdd2
```

A variable named `myAdd2`

```
 : (baseValue: number, increment: number) => number
```

Whose type is a function that takes a number called `baseValue` and another number called `increment`, and returns a number.

```
= function (x, y) {
  return x + y;
};
```

and whose value is this function here.

In the case of `myAdd`, the function's type is not explicitly specified. The  `: (baseValue: number, increment: number) => number` part is left out. So its type *inferred* based on the value being assigned to it.